# What code to use in R 3.5.1 to count numbers of unique var2 for each unique var1?

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I have a data with 2 columns. Var1 - school classes, Var2 - names of students in the class. What command can I use to make a new matrix that will show how many times are repeated unique names in var2 for each unique var1?

```
Var1     Var2
9      Sarah
9      John
12     Sarah
11     Veronica
10     John
10     John
11     Veronica
12     John
12     Veronica
11     Veronica
10     Sarah
9      Veronica
9      John
```

What command can I use to make a new matrix that      will show how many times are repeated unique names in var2 for each unique var1?

```
 _____Sarah____Veronica__John
9______1_______1___________2
10_____1_______0___________1
11_____0_______3___________0
12_____1_______1___________1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: table(df$Var1,df$Var2)

Answer (score 1):

You want a contigency table:

```
df <- data.frame(Var1, Var2)
xtabs(~Var1 + Var2, df)
#    Var2
#Var1 John Sarah Veronica
#  9     2     1        1
#  10    2     1        0
#  11    0     0        3
#  12    1     1        1
```

To count the number of unique combinations, you can use subset to remove the duplicates, and then calculate the column sums:

```
z <- xtabs(~Var1 + Var2, df, subset=!duplicated(df))
colSums(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the table function

```
var1 <- c(9, 9, 12, 11, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 11, 10, 9, 9)
var2 <- c("Sarah", "John", "Sarah", "Veronica", "John",
          "John", "Veronica", "John" ,"Veronica", 
          "Veronica", "Sarah", "Veronica", "John")
table(var1, var2)
```